# Quando é que um ditongo é crescente ou decrescente?

Tags: ortografia, vocabulário

Ditongo é o encontro de uma vogal com uma semivogal.
Como nas palavras a seguir.

> Exemplo:
>   Pai, água, peixe, etc

Quando é que um ditongo é crescente ou decrescente?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ditongo crescente — aquele que é composto por uma semivogal seguida de uma vogal (como *ua* em *quatro* ou *ia* em *ária*).
>
> ditongo decrescente — aquele que é composto por uma vogal seguida de uma semivogal (como *ei* em *reinado* ou *eu* em *pneu*).

Fonte: "[ditongo](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/ditongo)", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013,  [consultado em 23-07-2015].

---

Note-se que só contam para ditongo as vogais que estejam na mesma sílaba.
Assim, *pau* tem um ditongo, mas [*paul*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pa%C3%BAl) (pronunciado /pɐ'ul/) e *baú* (/ba'u/) não.

Comment: O elemento que falta aqui é (acho) que um ditongo deve estar em apenas uma sílaba. A palavra *ária* é /ˈa.ɾi.ɐ/  com três sílabas, o é /ˈa.ɾjɐ/ com duas?  Só no segundo caso temos ditongo crescente. Não vejo nada sobre um ditongo putativo /ja/  [aqui no português](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology#Oral_diphthongs), mas sim [aqui no castelhano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology#Diphthongs_and_triphthongs). Fico um pouco confuso. :)

Comment: @tchrist bom exemplo. Mas não consigo encontrar uma boa maneira de incorporar ditongos putativos na minha resposta.

Comment: Se você desconsiderar os sons /kʷ, gʷ/ de "qua, gua" (que a meu ver não são ditongos, mas consoantes labializadas, tal como no latim) então a língua Portuguesa não possui ditongos crescentes. Os encontros vocálicos de palavras como "[ciência](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ci%c3%aancia)" e "[águia](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/%C3%A1guia)" são descritos normalmente como hiatos. Nós lusófonos odiamos tanto ditongos crescentes que todos os que herdamos transformamos em decrescentes (compare o espanhol "Dios escribió a yo", que mantêm ditongos crescentes, com nosso "Deus escreveu a eu").

Comment: O Priberam refere até a estrangeirismos como hiatos. Segundo o site, "[Ioio](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ioio)" tem quatro sílabas em vez de duas.

Answer (score 3):

Ditongo é o encontro vocálico, numa única sílaba, de uma semivogal + vogal (ditongo crescente) ou vogal + semivogal (ditongo decrescente).

Ao estudar os ditongos, consideramos:
vogais: os sons /a/, /e/, /o/ semivogais: os sons: /i/ /u/, representando semitons.

Assim, os encontros vocálicos formados por semivogal + vogal constituem os ditongos crescentes (ia, ua, etc); os constituídos por vogal + semivogal são os decrescentes: (ai, ei etc).

Ditongos crescentes
Orais:
á-gua, a-qua-re-la, au-sên-cia, fér-reo, gê-nio, his-tó-ria, Lú-cia, sé-rie etc.

Nasais:
quanto, fre-quên-cia, pin-guim etc.

Ditongos decrescentes
Orais:
auto, cai-xa, fa-lei, fei-xe, fugiu, lei, oito, pai-xão, pas-téis, per-deu, sal-mou-ra, seu, vai, vai-da-de etc.

Nasais:
cãi-bra, cem, mui-to, fa-lam etc.

Fonte:

http://www.lpeu.com.br/q/thf80

Comment: [Os ditongos do português são estes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology#Oral_diphthongs).

Comment: Devia dizer que /i/ e /u/ pode ser vogais *ou* semivogais, não que são sempre semivogais ou semitons. Veja só os seus exemplos com "ui" ou "iu".